# winappdbg NtWriteVirtualMemory handle error

Tags: python, debugging, winapi, windbg

I'm using winappdbg in order to set breakpoint on ntdll!NtWriteVirtualMemory.

My goal is to check if the memory protection of the remote process is page_execute.

So I succeeded set breakpoint on NtWriteVirtualMemory, the problem is that I got handle in 
one of the parameters in the function(for example 0x20) , but when I use it in the script it's invalid.

I tried using winappdbg.win32.VirtualQueryEx(got handle is invalid)

Any ideas?

```
def action_callback( event ):
    print "ntdll!NtWriteVirtualMemory was called!" 
    process = event.get_process()
    thread  = event.get_thread()
    # Get the address of the top of the stack.
    stack   = thread.get_sp()

    # Get the return address of the call.
    retAddress = process.read_pointer( stack)
    print "ret address " + hex(retAddress) 
    processHandle = process.read_pointer( stack+4 )
    print "processHandle " + hex(processHandle) 
    BaseAddress = process.read_pointer( stack+8 )
    print "BaseAddress " + hex(BaseAddress)
    Buffer = process.read_pointer( stack+12 )
    print "Buffer " + hex(Buffer)
    NumberOfBytesToWrite = process.read_pointer( stack+16 )
    print "NumberOfBytesToWrite " + hex(NumberOfBytesToWrite)
    NumberOfBytesWritten = process.read_pointer( stack+16 )
    print "NumberOfBytesWritten " + hex(NumberOfBytesWritten)
    print "====================="
    print "virtualQuery - " + VirtualQueryEx(int(processHandle), BaseAddress)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you're trying to do can never work - Win32 handles are only valid within the process that creates them, and you're trying to use a handle in your script that was created by the process you're debugging.

What you need to do is try to get the process ID instead. Process IDs are global, and you can create your own handles to them using OpenProcess(). You'll have to hook all of the functions that can return a process handle, get their parameters and return values, and from there you can map the foreign handles into process IDs.

Another choice is to try to resolve the handle into a process ID by calling GetProcessID() within the target process (it will fail if you do it from the script for the same reasons explained above). This is a bit tricky since code injection may fail at times, I'd recommend using more hooks instead. But if you want to try this out anyway, event.get_process().inject_code() is your friend: http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/doc/latest/reference/winappdbg.process.Process-class.html#inject_code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used DuplicateHandle. It worked fine!

```
source_pid = event.get_process().get_pid()
print 'source pid =', source_pid
source_phandle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, source_pid)
print 'source phandle =', source_phandle
current_phandle = win32process.GetCurrentProcess()
print 'current phandle =', current_phandle
duplicated_handle = win32api.DuplicateHandle(source_phandle, processHandle, current_phandle,
                        0, FALSE, win32con.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)                   
print 'dup h =', duplicated_handle
source_process_name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(source_phandle, 0)
print "source_process_name - ",  (source_process_name)

q = VirtualQueryEx(duplicated_handle.handle, BaseAddress)
print "virtualQuery - is_executable()  " + str(q.is_executable())
target_process_name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(duplicated_handle.handle, 0)
print "target_process_name - ",  (target_process_name)
```

VirtualQueryEx works fine!

The problem now that GetModulefileNameEx to the duplicated handle returns me "the handle is invalid".

How can I reveal the target process name?

Thanks!